# How to run two virtual hosts on the same server in apache

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, php, ruby-on-rails

I've followed instructions on running two web apps in apache and my current confs are like this:

- apache2.conf: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1547286/
- httpd.conf: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1547288/
- ports.conf: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1547290/

I have a php web app on port 80 and a rails app on port 88. The php app works fine but the rails app won't load (timeout) if i try to go to virtualdiscoverycenter.net:88. If I switch it and make the rails app 80 and the php app 88, the rails app works but php won't load. It's obviously not a rails or php problem. I added port 80 and 88 to the iptables but it still won't work. Any insight or help would be greatly appreciated. If you want to see outputs of certain commands, just let me know.
Thanks.

--edit: I also disabled iptables and ufw but still got a timeout.. I'm so confused.
--edit2: It turns out I couldn't use those ports for something. It's working great on port 8000. Thanks for all the help, sorry about this..

Comment: Can you provide your iptables rules?

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1547439/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the IPtables rules you need to allow traffic to port 88.

```
iptables -A INPUT-p tcp --dport 88 -j ACCEPT
```

This should open port 88 so you can connect to the program running on it.

You might want to take a look at installing [Phusion Passenger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phusion_Passenger) on your Apache server, this will allow you run your PHP and Rails app on the same port and it is very easy to [install](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/download#open_source)

Comment: Ooh I have passenger but I didn't know you could deploy php stuff with it. Ill look into that, thanks.

Comment: I gave you the right answer because the problem was some weird port issues. The connection wouldn't let me in on 88, 90, 81, 8080, or a bunch of others, but 8000 works great.. Keep that in mind if anyone else has this issue. Try other ports! haha.

Comment: Well, Apache will still need the PHP handler installed for PHP to work but both will work together so you have Ruby and PHP code on the same Apache server

Answer (score 2):

Some years ago I have to do this in my work, I use mod_rewrite and my problems were solved.

Please see:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html

You can make something like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName j0hntheman.com

    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    <Proxy *>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    ProxyPass / http://205.234.222.223:8087/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://205.234.222.223:8087/

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^/ /SPL/ [L,P,R]
</VirtualHost>
```

Then make another, and when the connections goes to your 80 or 443 they found the right server. ;-) Hope it helps!

Comment: I'm not sure how I would use this to do what I need? Would I have it look for like /example then have it redirect to my /var/www/ app? then loook for /example_2 and redirect to /home/bakis/vdc/?

Comment: Hi! You need to put an apache in the front and your server applications with another port. The **VirtualHost** entry two times in your config file, which the first is the _hostname1_ and the second the _hostname2_, put these two entries with '**<VirtualHost *:80>**' so they'll found when some user try to connect in port 80. Then the '**RewriteEngine**' will do the magic, just put the servers that u want with the addr:port, something like: http://192.168.1.2:8081 for _host1_ and http://192.168.1.3:8082 for _host2_ and put these on '**ProxyPass**' tags. Hope it helps :) Sorry for my english! :]

Answer (score 0):

What  happens if you put

`NameVirtualHost *:88`

`NameVirtualHost *:80`

Instead of

`NameVirtualHost *:80`

`NameVirtualHost *:88`

?

Comment: Nothing happened. I still get a timeout when trying to hping it or access it in a browser.